# Is IIS a requirement in order to use AppFabric Server functionality for WCF Services?

Tags: wcf, iis, appfabric

I'm about to build a set of WCF Services. Previously I have written service-library DLL's and self hosted. However this new environment requires services to be deployed to AppFabric. It's my experience with AppFabric that it requires a .svc file, which must be hosted in IIS.

If I want to use AppFabric for my WCF services (Cacheing, Monitoring, Relay etc.) do I *HAVE* to use IIS? Or are there other options available to me? If so, what are those available options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far i know, all App Fabric requires is service to be hosted on WAS. By not having IIS you wont be able to use the IIS UI but i guess there would be command line options for this.

please have a look into :[App Fabric FAQ](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/appfabric-faq-hosting.aspx)

Comment: Yes, you can use the WAS either with IIS or without, there are plenty of options it seems, for others interested the following link is a wealth of good hosting examples: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752258(v=VS.90).aspx

Comment: Have IIS greatly increases the manageability of the setup, in regards to config and logs.